# How wrap the text inside the absolute div

Tags: html, css, onsen-ui, onsen-ui2

I'm using Vue Onsen UI for creating a progressive web app. I have a title which can be a little long and I'm placing it in the center expecting it to wrap normally, but it doesn't. The `toolbar` class is positioned absolutely.

Here is a [working example](https://onsen.io/v2/api/vue/v-ons-toolbar.html) on the website.

To test it we would need to increase the size of the text inside the `div.center`.

Can someone help me understand and fix this issue? Let me know if some more information is required.

Answer (score 0):

It appears as though the CSS class 'center' is overriding the **white-space** and **line-height** properties. The following will work for you,

```
.multiline-center {
   height:100%; 
   display: flex; 
   align-items: center; 
   justify-content: center; 
   white-space:normal; 
   line-height:12pt
}

<div class="center">
    <div class="multiline-center">
        {{ title }}
    </div>
</div>
```